# How does GetCallbackChannel() work on a duplex wcf channel?

Tags: wcf

When a service is working with a duplex binding in WCF, you can do this within an operation:

```
OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientReceiver>()
```

to get a reference to the caller. What is that reference? I mean, it looks like it's doing some voo-doo magic. What is happening behind the scenes that allows the service to send a message back to the client?

And how does this work differently on a TCP binding vs. duplex http binding? Because I understand TCP can natively call back to the client, but http can't so it has to create a second channel on the server side to call down to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `WSDualHttpBinding` there are actually two HTTP connections: one from the client to the server, one from the server to the client. `GetCallbackChannel<T>` will return a reference to a channel which knows how to send messages to the client, and, as you pointed out, is dependent on the underlying transport.

Comment: Thanks carlosfigueira. How does the TCP binding do callbacks if it doesn't create a second channel like HTTP? Do you know?

Comment: TCP is already a bi-directional channel, so no additional channel is needed for that. TCP is just a think layer on top of raw sockets, which are full duplex.